# How to add additional weight to shortest path?

Tags: cost-path, network-analysis

I am calculating shortest bath between two points. I need to add an additional feature eg. air toxicity in my calculation, so that the shortest path calculated takes into account the air toxicity and gives the least toxic path. How can I  do this?

Comment: please add how exactly you are doing it currently; software, data etc.

Comment: I am using network analysis tool>shortest path in QGIS 3.6 I am getting an output layer of shortest path. But I need to include other parameter in this calculation, Radiation Dose to be exact. I have a raster file of radiation dose in the area. Now I need the software to consider this dose in addition to other parameters (Max speed, Direction, etc)

Comment: QGIS' own routing tools are optimized for the most common use cases. if yours needs more sophisticated modeling, consider moving to more versatile frameworks like *pgRouting* for *PostgreSQL/PostGIS*. that being said, while it's not a generic 'cost' attribute, you could still utilize the `Speed field` value here: have the radiation intensity lower the max speed of an edge. This needs careful formulation, but it's possible. Getting meaningful radiation intensities assigned to each edge is more involved and might be suitable for another question (or research on existing solutions).

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide clarifications. It's not fair to those who would answer to force them to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: I have almost the same needs. I have tree layerst: start_point layer, end_point layer and  network line layer. Start_point layer has one point, end_point layer has many point s... (one-to-many). Network layer has node_id, source_point, target_point and weight value. I want to calculate the shortest route one-to-many, taking into account in every route the weight of each node ... shortest and lowest cost (sum of weight) path is the best solution. One restriction: one-to-many routes must not overlap. Outcome is many different routes as many as there are endpoints.

Comment: In QGIS is Least Cost Path plugin ... I want almost the same output, but instead of raster layer I want to use for calculations vector networked layer.